# missing assembly reference viewport c# wp8 xna

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, xna, viewport

I was recreating this sample about using motion API for creating an Augmented Reality app for WP8.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202984(v=vs.105).aspx/css#BKMK_CreatingaSilverlightbasedAugmentedRealityApplication

I followed everything right. Used the correct using statements too. But the Viewport is not detected as a class in microsoft.xna.framework.graphics or microsoft.xna.framework. 
I tried to look everywhere on the internet regarding this, but in vain. I even installed the xna framework to get those dll files for microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.dll and others. But when I add the dlls manually as references I get the following error.

**"A reference to a higher version or an incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project."**

Without viewport, the app is useless.

How do I add the xna framework class library to VS2012 so that my app looks at that dll file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Viewport class in WP8. However there was the same problem with the [GART toolkit](http://gart.codeplex.com/), and it was solved by implementing a Viewport class. You can go to the project page and browse the [source code](http://gart.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) to see how it is implemented:

http://gart.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GeoARToolkit/NonXnaUtils/Viewport.cs